# Glide crashes app on loading an animated jpg

Tags: java, android, exception, android-glide

So, I'm loading photos from imgur using Glide with the code below.

```
try {
    ViewTarget viewTarget = new ViewTarget<SubsamplingScaleImageView, BitmapDrawable>(image_view) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(BitmapDrawable bitmap, Transition<? super BitmapDrawable> transition) {
            this.view.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap.getBitmap()));
        }
    };

    GlideApp.with(this).load(post_to_show.getUrl()).into(viewTarget);
} catch (ClassCastException e){}
```

where SubsamplingScaleImageView is - well - a Custom ImageView extending View.
But it doesn't matter here.

It's working fine, until I try loading something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/DyPF53S.jpg)

It has a .jpg extension, but it's a gif.

I get this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: me.ekhaled667.ridit, PID: 6202
>                                                                      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gif.GifDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
>                                                                          at me.ekhaled667.ridit.PostFragment$1.onResourceReady(PostFragment.java:257)
>                                                                          at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:579)
>                                                                          at com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.onResourceReady(SingleRequest.java:549)
>                                                                          at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.handleResultOnMainThread(EngineJob.java:218)
>                                                                          at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$MainThreadCallback.handleMessage(EngineJob.java:324)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6348)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)

First: why wasn't it caught as an exception?

Second: How can I possibly go around this, or put another way, know that this is a gif not a jpg and load it properly?

Comment: why does that have .jpg even it's a gif. Gif is supported by Glide

Comment: I honestly don't know, but it's breaking my code.

How can I detect that it's not a .jpg?

Comment: load this https://i.imgur.com/DyPF53S.gif

Comment: I think you can catch the exception and if its a classcast exception you can replace the jpg with gif and reload the image.

Comment: I can't catch the exception.
I think because it's FATAL it crashes the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured a way for this to work thanks to @Kaushal Gosaliya, but GIFs will be displayed as static images only.

```
ViewTarget viewTarget = new ViewTarget<SubsamplingScaleImageView, Drawable>(image_view) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                Bitmap mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(resource.getIntrinsicWidth(), resource.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                resource.setBounds(0, 0, resource.getIntrinsicWidth(), resource.getIntrinsicHeight());
                resource.draw(canvas);

                this.view.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(mutableBitmap));
            }
        };
```

This is the ViewTarget you want to use, where you change BitmapDrawable to Drawable to encompass all drawables.
Then you convert the drawable to a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You Can show gif using this code.

```
load=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loadimg);

GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(load);
Glide.with(this).load(post_to_show.getUrl()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imageViewTarget);
```

Comment: I can show gifs, but I have to know there it's a gif to load it instead of a gif.

If this can do both, then how can I do this with a custom View?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code it may be helpfull :

[Dependency](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.imageView)SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        gifImage();
    }

    public void gifImage(){

        ViewTarget viewTarget = new ViewTarget<SubsamplingScaleImageView,GifDrawable>(imageView) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull GifDrawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super GifDrawable> transition) {
                this.view.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(resource.getFirstFrame()));
            }
        };

        Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load("https://metrouk2.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/giphy9.gif?w=748&h=561&crop=1")
                .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(viewTarget);

    }


}
```

**XML File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Image file:**

```
public class GlideActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.imageView)ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_glide);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        gifImage();
    }

    public void gifImage() {

        Glide.with(this).load("http://imagesourceteam.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/rr.jpg").into(imageView);

    }
}
```

**activity_glide.xml file.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much.
However it displays a still image. I would appreciate if you have a solution that treats it as a gif.

Comment: Actually, now it doesn't load images, only gifs first frame.

Comment: @KhaledEmara I have added the code of How to load an image with use of glide please check. It may be helpful to solve your issue.

Comment: I think you don't get what I want.    
I can play GIFs and display JPEGs, the problem is: I can't decide whether it's a GIF or JPEG.    
So a GIF disguised as a JPEG will crash the app.    
If I only use your first solution images won't be displayed.    
and If I only use your second solution an animated GPEG will crash the app.
Correct me if I'm wrong.   
Anyways, thank you very much you helped a lot and put me on the right path to solve the problem.    
I'll upvote this once my reputation allow.